# the activity life cycle of the android tabhost

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I am trying to use a tabhost that contains 3 tabs

I also have a button within the tabhost that can be clicked no matter what activity is in the frameLayout. (this button returns back to a previous non tab activity)

When one of my tab activites is paused it stores some information.(So every time i switch tab information is stored).

what i am having trouble with is, when i press the button , i call

```
TabbedActivity.this.finish();
```

the onPause and onStop method of the activity within the frame layout is not called.

how would i go about calling these methods before i call the `.finish()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure my onPause method was called.... i just called

```
if(tabHost.getCurrentTab() !=0){
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            }else{
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
            }


            PinMeTabbedActivity.this.finish();
```